# Does addition of HCl favour, or disfavour, formation of tetraamminecopper(II)?

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, coordination-compounds

Which way does the equilibrium

$$\ce{[Cu(H2O)4]^2+(aq) + 4 NH3(aq) <=> [Cu(NH3)4]^2+ (aq) + 4 H2O (l)}$$

shift if HCl is added to the system?

When I did this experiment, I found that the original solution was rather cloudy, but adding HCl made it clear. I suspect that it was moving towards the more soluble side of the reaction, but I can't find the solubilities of the copper compounds.

Comment: What type of reagent is HCl? What type of reagent would HCl react with? Is there anything in this system with that property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HCl reacts with ammonia and removes it from the equilibrium above:

$$\ce{HCl + NH3 <=> NH4+ + Cl-}$$

therefore the equilibrium will shift to the left.

Comment: Can't HCl also do this with water?

Comment: Yes it could, but then you form $\ce{H3O+}$ which would react with NH3 anyway... If you are adding aqueous HCl, it is already fully dissociated, so in fact you are basically adding $\ce{H3O+}$ to your solution.